# Confused about the different results between using Python 2.7 and Python 3.4

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.4

When I ran the following Python code, I got different results using Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, I have no idea why...

```
import sys

def main():
    total = 0
    number = 568

    while number:
        total += number % 10
        print("total = %d" % total)
        number /= 10


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output result using Python 2.7:

total = 8

total = 14

total = 19

Output result using Python 3.4(I deleted some output because it's too long):

total = 8

total = 14

total = 20

total = 21

total = 21

total = 21

..........

Comment: See [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) - it will shed (quite) some light on your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2.X implements integer division, so 568 / 10 = 56.

Python 3.X implements true division, so 568 / 10 = 56.8.

Change `"total = %d"` to `"total = %f"` to see the difference.

To force integer division, use `//` instead of `/`.

To make Python 2 work like Python 3, add `from __future__ import division` to the top of the script.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks a lot.